# remote web server compilation?

Tags: php, javascript, compilation, ssh

So I'm kind of tossing an idea around in my head... is it feasible to write a webapp that asks for a user to input a snippet of code, and then compiles it remotely on a server, and returns the output back to the user?

Comment: Like http://ideone.com/ you mean?

Comment: I expect [Codepad](http://codepad.org/) does this. They will have dealt with all sorts of sec issues, so you might want to read up [here](http://codepad.org/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

feasible sure, you could definitely make this work from a technical point of view. but in terms of security, it sounds very dangerous.

Comment: I definitely agree with you and Gordon about security... I was thinking of just having a VM on the server responsible for compilation... I don't know the technical details about trying to ssh to a VM though.